# Find rows of matrix which contain rows of another matrix

Tags: r, math, matrix, operation

Suppose I have an m x n matrix M1 and an k x l matrix M2 with l <= n. I want to find all those rows in M1 that contain some row of M2 in it.

For example consider the following situation:

```
> M1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
> M2 <- matrix(c(1,3,8,9), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
> M1
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    4    5    6
 [3,]    7    8    9
> M2
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    3
 [2,]    8    9
```

Then rows one and three of M1 fulfill the condition, as row one contains 1 and 3 and the last row 8 and 9.

So how to achieve this in an efficient way? I have written code using loops, but as I am working with very large matrices this solution takes to much time.

Comment: You could consider representing `M1` and `M2` as `table(row(M1), factor(M1, 1:9))` and `table(row(M2), factor(M2, 1:9))`, respectively. That way, you could find any relation between rows in a more straightforward way. Falling to the sparse alternatives, since else there 'll be memory issues, `library(Matrix); tab1 = sparseMatrix(i = row(M1), j = M1, x = 1L); tab2 = sparseMatrix(i = row(M2), j = M2, x = 1L); tcrossprod(tab1, tab2)`. The last object counts the co-occurences between each row of `M1` and `M2` and can be compared to `nrow(M2)` to extract your result.

Comment: @StefanH If any of the answers below solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

More general example:

```
M1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2), nrow = 6, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
M2 <- matrix(c(1,2,6,9, 10,11,16,17, 19, 2), nrow = 5, ncol =2, byrow = TRUE)
```

First, use `match` to find indexes of the matching values in `M1`.

```
ind <- match(M1, M2)
```

Now, using the mod operator `%%` with the indexes and the number of rows, you'll find the rows. This works because the indexes will always be the `M2` row plus the total number of rows, so numbers in the same row will return the same result.

```
rows <- ind %% nrow(M2)
```

Then, `m` is a matrix containing row number of matching values between `M1` and `M2`. Lines will only be selected if the same index appear in the same row 2 times (or, more generally, the number of times equal to the number of columns in `M2`). This assures that a row of `M1` is only be considered if it contains all elements of a row in `M2`.

```
m <- matrix(rows, nrow = nrow(M1))
matchRows <- apply(m, 1, duplicated, incomparables = NA)
M1rows <- which(colSums(matchRows)==ncol(M2)-1)
```

Comment: The third line seems like magic to me, I do not know why is this working, is it also working for the general case?

Comment: @StefanH I updated the post, adding a more general example, and explaining the code. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks, but I do not meant the problem that specific. Your solution just works if all the rows of M2 are contained somewhere in the rows of M1. But that does not has to be the case, consider M2 <- matrix(c(1,4,8,910,11,16,17), nrow = 4, ncol =2, byrow = TRUE) where the result is wrong. Image the rows in M2 as numbers for which I want to know if they are contained in the rows of M1, where it is perfectly valid that just one number occurs in a row of M1, but these cases I do not want to count.

Comment: @StefanH Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Let's see how it does now, I tested with different matrix sizes and cases. Let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: @StefanH I added some upgrades, considering possible duplicates of rows in `M1`. I also think the code is cleaner now.

Answer (score 1):

This method will check each row from M2 and will return the row index from M1 if it is contained or NA in case it is not

```
M1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
> M1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9

M2 <- matrix(c(1,3,8,5,4,5,1,2), nrow = 4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
> M2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    8    5
[3,]    4    5
[4,]    1    2

y = apply(M2,1,function(x){
  z = unique(which(M1 %in% x)%%nrow(M1))
  ifelse(length(z)==1,ifelse(z==0,nrow(M1),z),NA)
})

> y
[1]  1 NA  2  1
```

This means that row 2 from M2 is not in M1, and that rows 1 and 4 from M2 are in row 1 in M1. Also row 3 in M2 is in row 2 in M1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not working if some row of M2 occurs multiple times, for example for M1 = matrix(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE).