# efficient way to disconnect graphs while maximising edges weight

Tags: python, r, optimization, graph, igraph

Given a connected graph and a list of N-assigned vertexes, I want to find an efficient way to create N subgraphs, each containing one of the assigned vertexes.
To achieve that, we can prune the edges. However, we should prune less edge weight as possible.

For example, let's start with the following graph. We want to obtain three subgraphs containing one of the three red vertexes [image]

The result should look like the following:
[image]

Right now, I'm using a heuristic, but it is not working well in some edge cases and has n^2 complexity on the number of vertexes. The idea is to calculate the shortest path between two vertex and remove the lightest edge and repeat until the vertex are disconnected.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import igraph as ig
from collections import Counter

ucg_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0, 1, 100],
        [0, 2, 110],
        [2, 3, 70],
        [3, 4, 100],
        [3, 1, 90],
        [0, 3, 85],
        [5, 7, 90],
        [0, 8, 100],
        [3, 6, 10],
        [2, 5, 60],
    ],
    columns=["nodeA", "nodeB", "weight"],
)

ucg_graph = ig.Graph.DataFrame(ucg_df, directed=False)

ig.plot(
    ucg_graph,
    target='stack1.pdf',
    edge_label=ucg_graph.es["weight"],
    vertex_color=['red']*3 +  ['green']*(len(ucg_df)-3),
    vertex_label = ucg_graph.vs.indices
)



def generate_subgraphs_from_vertexes(g, vertex_list):
    for i, vertex in enumerate(vertex_list):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(vertex_list)):
            while True:
                path = g.get_shortest_paths(vertex_list[i], vertex_list[j], mode='ALL', output='epath',
                                     weights='weight')[0]
                if len(path) == 0:
                    break
                edge_2_drop = min(g.es[path], key=lambda x: x['weight'])
                edge_2_drop.delete()

    return g
graph = generate_subgraphs_from_vertexes(ucg_graph, ucg_graph.vs[0,1,2])


ig.plot(
    graph,
    target='stack2.pdf',
    edge_label=graph.es["weight"],
    vertex_color=['red']*3 +  ['green']*(len(ucg_df)-3),
    vertex_label = graph.vs.indices
)
```

what kind of algorithm could I use to better solve this problem?

Comment: Minimum cut https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. On separating subgraphs of n, what are the rules? Include n, not other red nodes, include the connected node of the lowest weight and then all of its connected nodes except red ones?

Comment: This is the multi-terminal cut problem, and it is NP-hard for more than two terminals. I am not familiar with the (approximation) methods to solve it so I cannot give you more than this keyword to search for.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `igraph` in Python, but below is my attempt in `R`. Hope you can get some hint here.

---

I think your problem can be reformulated into an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), since the key part is assigning "red" to associated "green" vertices to maximize the cost

```
library(igraph)
library(lpSolve)

# red vertices
vred <- V(g)[V(g)$color == "red"]

# subgraph that contains vred
sg <- induced.subgraph(
  g,
  unique(unlist(ego(g, 1, vred)))
)

# green vertices in sg
vgreen <- V(sg)[V(sg)$color == "green"]

# cost matrix
cost.mat <- get.adjacency(sg, attr = "label", sparse = FALSE)[vred, ][, vgreen]
p <- lp.assign(cost.mat, "max")
idx <- which(p$solution > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
# edge list for max assignment
el1 <- cbind(names(vred[idx[, 1]]), names(vgreen[idx[, 2]]))

# all edges associated with vred
el <- get.edgelist(g)
el2 <- el[rowSums(matrix(el %in% names(vred), ncol = 2)) > 0, ]

# remove edges that are not obtained for the max assignment
rmEls <- do.call(
  paste,
  c(
    data.frame(
      el2[!apply(el2, 1, function(x) toString(sort(x))) %in% apply(el1, 1, function(x) toString(sort(x))), ]
    ),
    sep = "|"
  )
)
out <- g %>%
  delete.edges(rmEls)
```

When running `plot(out, layout = layout_nicely(g))`, you will see
[image]

---

## Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  from = c(0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 5, 0, 3, 2),
  to = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 7, 8, 6, 5),
  weight = c(100, 110, 70, 100, 90, 85, 90, 100, 10, 60)
)

# original graph object
g <- df %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
  set_edge_attr(name = "label", value = df$weight) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "color", value = ifelse(names(V(.)) %in% c("0", "1", "2"), "red", "green"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by
[Find rows of matrix which contain rows of another matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779719/find-rows-of-matrix-which-contain-rows-of-another-matrix),
I found, assuming the graph is undirected:

```
    mtch  <- matrix(match(el2, el1), ncol = 2)
    idx   <- which(abs(mtch[,1] - mtch[,2]) == nrow(el1))
    rmEls <- get.edge.ids(g, t(el2[-idx,]))
    rmEls
    ## [1] 1 2 3 6
```